# Help to fill PSP forms and module

Tags: process, personal-software-process

Hi guys wanto to try PSP personal software process.
I have no tutor and i'm in mess with compiling forms.

for example, in Project Summary, for phases of process what's 
“To Date” is the total actual to-date values for all products developed.
?

there are online some resources for linux or some completed examples?

i've downloaded psp-dashboard but i think their authors should study somethin like .. human-machine-interaction because it's really an-usable.

Answer (score 3):

The best method of learning the Personal Software Process is to purchase the two books by Watts S. Humphrey: [PSP: A Self-Improvement Process for Software Engineers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321305493) and [A Discipline for Software Engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201546108). These two books walk you through PSP0 through PSP3, teaching you about the forms. There are also sections about making modifications to the PSP to tailor it to your specific needs. If you are looking for online references, the best source is probably the [Software Engineering Institute's Personal Software Process/Team Software Process website](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/tsp/start/index.cfm), and more specifically the [Personal Software Process Body of Knowledge](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/tsp/tools/bok/).

To answer your specific question, the "to date" values are the sum of the "actual" value for the current project and the value from "to date" for that step from your most recently developed program. The first time you use the PSP, "actual" and "to date" will be the same, unless you were tracking this metric under your old process as well. After this, the "to date" will increase as you spend more time on each step on every project. It's simply a cumulative counter of time spent on a given activity across all projects.